# How do I use this Django app correctly?

Tags: python, django, installation

https://github.com/jtauber/django-notification/tree/555b506a3e225d476d17939d8b43f853fd0226ec/notification

OK, so this is what I did so far:

- Install this via setup.py install
- put "notification" in INSTALLED_APPS
- import notification in my views.py

After looking at the source code of that app, it seems like there is URLs.py inside the app. Also, there is a templates folder.

What do I do with these?  I already have a urls.py in my project directory....so how do I point my current urls.py to that one?

Did I install this correctly? Was I supposed to copy the entire directory to my project directory, instead of going through setup.py install?

Comment: Oh come on... http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you recommend copying the notification folder into my root project directory as an app, or should I keep it in my site-packages, and import from there?

Comment: https://github.com/jtauber/django-notification/blob/555b506a3e225d476d17939d8b43f853fd0226ec/docs/usage.txt

Comment: Why would you *ever* put anything in your project directory that you didn't have to?

Answer (score 0):

Use setup.py, and install it into your project's virtualenv.

If you aren't using virtualenv for development, and probably deployment, then you should be.

Oh, and obligatory docs link for including urls.py: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs (hat-tip to Ignacio).